# nth Veronese subring embedding induces isomorphism of schemes (Vakil FOAG 6.4.D)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, projective-schemes

Exact exercise is: show the embedding map of graded rings $S_{n\bullet} \to S_\bullet$ for $S_\bullet$ finitely generated graded ring induces an isomorphism $\operatorname{Proj} S_\bullet \to \operatorname{Proj}S_{n\bullet}$. The hint is to show that we can set up isomorphisms of $D(f) \to D(f)$ for $f \in S_+$ homogeneous degree $n$, which is sufficiently clear by considering zero components of localized rings and by considering that $D(f)$ cover $\operatorname{Proj}S_\bullet$ (which is simply by considering that the proj construction starts by taking sets of primes and so for $f_i$ generators of $S_\bullet$ we can see $D(f_i^n) = D(f_i)$). So far, have successfully done everything up to showing that we get a sheaf isomorphism (meaning considering the schemes to be sheaves on the same space via the inverse map on open sets gives an isomorphism of sheaves) since the isomorphisms of the distinguished opens give isomorphisms of stalks. However, it still remains to show that the induced map is a homeomorphism (i.e. that it is a set isomorphism with a continuous inverse). I get stuck here, since I think the isomorphism induces on distinguished opens does not necessarily mean that the map as a whole is a set isomorphism with a continuous inverse. I'd love any hints on how to wrap this up.

Comment: You already have a map of Projs and you can check that it's an isomorphism on an open cover, so it must be an isomorphism everywhere. I would suggest writing this out carefully if you don't believe me - you already have continuity and you can check injectivity, surjectivity, and open-ness of the topological map on an open cover to see it must be a homeomorphism

Comment: Why does injectivity, surjectivity and openness locally (which is what I assume you meant by "on an open cover") imply homeomorphism? The whole idea of a covering space is predicated on having local homeomorphisms without having a global homeomorphism for instance. I see that local isomorphisms given global isomorphism of sheaves - I just need a hint on how to show we have a homeomorphism here (specifically, showing injectivity, surjectivity and continuity of inverse). Thank you.

Comment: Let $f:X\to Y$ be such that it's a homeomorphism when restricted to some open cover, ie $f^{-1}(U_i)\to U_i$ is a homeomorphism for an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $Y$. Suppose $x$ and $x'$ map to $y$. Pick $U_i$ containing $y$. As $f^{-1}(U_i)\to U_i$ is injective, $x=x'$. Everything else happens similarly. The key difference with covering space arguments is there you're picking a cover locally on the source, and here you're picking one locally on the target.

Comment: Thank you. The only piece that does not quite click for me is that in the construction of this map we localize to find isomorphisms of the $D(f)$, but at no point do we assume that each $D(f)$ in the domain is the pre-image of the corresponding $D(f)$ in the target? I.e. can't you choose $f, f'$ s.t. $D(f)=D(f')$ in the target but $D(f) \not = D(f')$ in the domain?

Comment: I think you ought to be able to prove that yourself if it's bugging you: remember the map is taking the intersection of a graded prime $p$ with $S_{n\bullet}$, so if $f$ has the right degree, $f$ is in $p$ iff $f$ is in $p\cap S_{n\bullet}$, right?

Comment: I need to think about this more, but I did not think to use the correspondence of zero components of localized graded rings with certain homogeneous primes, which as you suggest solves this if it translates to mean what you suggest here. Thanks! Super helpful.

Comment: You find an elementary example here that may be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4026028/an-explicit-construction-of-the-veronese-embedding/4026410#4026410