# How to show $ \phi: \mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow X, \quad\left[x_0: x_1\right] \mapsto\left[x_0^2: x_1^2: x_0 x_1\right] $ is a morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Show that
$$
\phi: \mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow X, \quad\left[x_0: x_1\right] \mapsto\left[x_0^2: x_1^2: x_0 x_1\right]
$$
is an isomorphism, i.e. it is a regular map that admits a regular inverse.

So we know the characterization of morphisms from the projective algebraic set is defined by locally by polynomial functions all homogeneous of the same degree and nonvanishing at the same time. So the map itself is obviously a morphism, so we just need to find the inverse which is where things get tricky. So it is unlikely that we can do this with one function, but since the definition of morphism is local, we can find two or more mappings defined on different open sets of $X$ that does the job. Now I know the solution but I am not sure what the general strategy is for getting there and tackling these types of problems. Can someone walk me through this problem?

Comment: Here is an "elementary" proof that the Veronese embedding is a closed immersion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4026028/an-explicit-construction-of-the-veronese-embedding/4026410#4026410

Comment: The idea is to construct an inverse morphism $f: v_2(\mathbb{P}^1) \cong \mathbb{P}^1$ using an open cover of $\mathbb{P}^2$. In the thread I do this in the "classical language", but a similar construction may be done "scheme theoretically".