Identifying curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ with curves in $\mathbb{P}^5$?
I am currently reading Hartshornes algebraic geometry and do its exercises. Right now I am struggling with exercise 2.13:

Let $Y$ be the image of the $2$-uple embedding of $\mathbb{P}^2$ in $\mathbb{P}^5$. This is the Veronese surface. If $Z\subseteq Y$ is a closed curve (a curve is a variety of dimension $1$), show that there exists a hypersurface $V\subseteq\mathbb{P}^5$ such that $V\cap Y=Z$.

Edit, to come more direct to the point of my question:
I have seen solutions on this exercise that assume that any such curve can be given by a polynomial $f(x,y,z)=0$. By my understanding, this is only the case for curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$. However, regarding how the exercise is stated, I would assume that $Z$ is a curve in $\mathbb{P}^5$. However, if $f(x,y,z)=0$ defines a curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$, and I interpret this exact same function as function on $\mathbb{P}^5$ as $f(x,y,z,u,v,w):=f(x,y,z)$ and just ignore the other three variables, the resulting variety has dimension $4$ and thus is not a curve anymore, right?
This follows from the fact that an variety in $\mathbb{P}^n$ has dimension $n-1$ iff its given by a single irreducible homogeneous polynomial.
So my question is, why is it sufficient to consider curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$? Or is it?  Is there any obvious way to identify any curve in  $\mathbb{P}^5$ as curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$?

This is not my expertise. What is this P ? Is it countable ? finite ? A surface ?

@mick This is all very standard notation and terminology: $\Bbb P^n$ is the projective space of dimension $n$, here over some ground field $k$. I would recommend doing some background reading and then asking a question of your own if you are still in need of some clarification - the level of context about $\Bbb P^n$ in this question is appropriate, in my opinion.

@KReiser thank you. I need to read more about this yes.

You do want to think of a curve in $\Bbb P^2$ and then of its image under the Veronese embedding. You do not want to be thinking about curves in $\Bbb P^5$.

It's important to keep track of where things are happening here. In $\Bbb P^2$ with  coordinates of $x,y,z$, every curve can be cut out by a single polynomial $f(x,y,z)$. In $\Bbb P^5$, as your reasoning explains, no curves can be cut out by a single polynomial. Instead, what we're asked to do here is to show that for any curve $Z\subset\Bbb P^5$ which lies on the Veronese surface $Y$, there is a polynomial $g(t_0,\cdots,t_5)$ in the coordinates $t_0,\cdots,t_5$ on $\Bbb P^5$ so that $V(g)\cap Y=Z$.
The first big idea here is to realize that since the Veronese map $\phi:\Bbb P^2\to\Bbb P^5$ is an isomorphism on to its image, the curve $Z$ is the same as a curve $C\subset\Bbb P^2$. So $C$ is cut out by some polynomial $f(x,y,z)$, and this polynomial $f(x,y,z)$ has to be our starting point for finding $g$.
Once we have this observation, what the question is asking you to show is that for any curve $C$ in $\Bbb P^2$, when we embed $\Bbb P^2$ in to $\Bbb P^5$ via $\varphi$, there is a single polynomial $g(t_0,\cdots,t_5)$ so that $V(g)\cap\varphi(\Bbb P^2) = \varphi(C)$.
Since $\varphi$ is an isomorphism on to its image, which the problem denotes $Y$, it's at least believable that there might be such a $g$: we have that $\varphi(C)$ is again closed, and one dimension smaller than $Y$, so we don't have anything stopping us at this point. I'd recommend playing around with a couple examples here before reading the following spoiler text which gives away how to solve the problem.

 The trick here is that if $f(x,y,z)$ is a polynomial cutting out $C$, then $f^2$ is also a polynomial vanishing on $C$, and $f^2$ can be written as a polynomial in $x^2,xy,xz,y^2,yz,z^2$, which are where $t_0,\cdots,t_5$ go when evaluated on $Y$. So taking $g$ to be a polynomial so that when you plug in the degree-two monomials for $t_i$ you get $f^2$ will solve the problem.


I really appreciate your help on this problem. I was unaware of the fact that the Veronese map $\phi:\mathbb{P}^2\to \mathbb{P}^5$ is an isomorphism onto its image.  As indicated by the answers on the question below, this also does not seem to be obvious at all.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4026028/an-explicit-construction-of-the-veronese-embedding

@HyperPro I don't think it's as bad as those answers make it look - locally on the image you can invert  the Veronese map, which is enough to show it's an isomorphism on to its image. For instance, if we write $[x:y:z]\mapsto[x^2:xy:xz:y^2:yz:z^2]$, then for any point in the image where $t_5\neq 0$, we can recover the point which mapped to that uniquely as $[t_2/t_5:t_4/t_5:1]=[x/z:y/z:1]=[x:y:z]$.

Thank you for this clarification. However, I noticed I am not too sufficiently familiar with the notion of morphism. For my understanding, as this inverse is only locally defined, shouldn't this mean that the varities are only birationally equivalent (hartshorne corollary 4.5)? Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I have only read the first chapter of Hartshorne so far.

@HyperPro No, the fact that we can invert it locally about every point of the image and these local inverses agree where they're defined means that they assemble to a fully-defined inverse map, giving that $\phi$ is an isomorphism on to its image. If there were points where there was no way to define a local inverse, then you would be stuck at birational equivalence but not isomorphism.
